# Strange behavior of JQGrid of reload grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Jqgrid is doing strange behavior in my application. I have a grid in which i set the grid params and then reload it. This is my code:

```
if (Id > 0) {
    var postData = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
    postData["CarId"] = carId;
    postData["filter"] = $searchTextbox.val() || null;
    postData["date"] = $State ? $CarState.val() : null;
    postData["processId"] = Dashboard.process ? Dashboard.process.ProcessId || null : null;
    filterGrid($grid, postData);  //Calling function
}
```

And this is my filterGrid function.

```
var filterGrid = function($grid, postData) {
    if ($grid) {
        debugger;
        if (postData && postData.length) { //"PROBLEM IS HERE"
            $grid.setGridParam({ postData: postData });
        }

        reloadGrid($grid); //This is a function which reload the grid
    }
};
```

Reload grid function

I just doing this in reload function

```
$grid.setGridParam({ datatype: "json", page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Now, the problem is, in filter grid function where i mentioned the "problem", that condition fails every time, but when jqgrid reload, it gives the correct result.How? Everything is working fine but my question is if condition fails then how setgrid params called. Result is correct after reload grid. What is the problem.

Comment: You posted short fragments of your code without the context where it will be used. The order or loading, filtering and reloading is absolutely unclear. It's unclear where you want use *server side* filtering or client side filtering.

Comment: @Oleg I know i give short fragment of my code.You always help in jqgrid problems. . I have no issue.My work is working right but  My question was how jqgrid give correct state if setgridparam is not called

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. You still not answered on my previous questions. I have no idea which scenario you use: client side filtering or server side filtering. Which "state" you mean ("how jqgrid give correct state")?

Comment: Its server side filtering. Jqgrid correct state means, it fetch correct record. I recive correct paramaeter at server side.

Comment: jqGrid fetch no records. it send/post (I have no idea about other parts of your code) just the standard parameters of jqGrid to `url` and your custom parameters (`CarId`, `filter`, `date`, `processId`). I can repeat that the small code agreements gives really too few information about what you do and what you want to ask.